# How to change shipping tracking URL on the order page (in admin)

Tags: magento2, shipment-tracking

Would anyone know how we can change the order tracking URL on the order page (admin) to the shipping URL? (.../admin/order_shipment/view/shipment_id/xxxx)
We have already managed to change the URL but we have not been able to set the shipping ID.

Thank you so much.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this via custom module.

Create block **Info.php** file Under the **Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View**

```
<?php
/**
 * Shipment view form
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
/**
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Info extends Template
{


    protected $_order;
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_order = $registry->registry('current_order');
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getShipmentId()
    {
        $shipmentId = null;
        if ($this->_order) {
            foreach ($this->_order->getShipmentsCollection() as $shipment) {
                $shipmentId = $shipment->getId();
                break;
            }
        }
        return $this->getUrl('admin/order_shipment/view', ['shipment_id' => $shipmentId]);
    }
}
```

Create view file **info.phtml** under the **Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */


/**
 * @var \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info $block
 */
$shippingHelper = $block->getData('shippingHelper');


$taxHelper = $block->getData('taxHelper');
?>
<?php $order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($order->getIsVirtual()):
    return '';
endif; ?>
<?php
if ($order->hasShipments()) {
    $shipment = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();
    $shipmentId = $shipment->getId();
} 
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info');
$customerUrl = $blockObj->getShipmentId();
?>
<?php /* Shipping Method */ ?>
<div class="admin__page-section-item order-shipping-method">
    <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
        <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shipping &amp; Handling Information')) ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
        <?php  if ($order->getTracksCollection()->count()): ?>
            <p>
                <a href="<?= /* @noEscape */ $customerUrl ?>" id="linkId" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Track Order')) ?>">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Track Order')) ?>
                </a>
            </p>
            <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderEventListenerAsTag(
                'onclick',
                "popWin('" . $block->escapeJs($shippingHelper->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($order)) .
                "','trackorder','width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')",
                'a#linkId'
            ) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($order->getShippingDescription()): ?>
            <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($order->getShippingDescription()) ?></strong>


            <?php if ($taxHelper->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()): ?>
                <?php $_excl = $block->displayShippingPriceInclTax($order); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php $_excl = $block->displayPriceAttribute('shipping_amount', false, ' '); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $_incl = $block->displayShippingPriceInclTax($order); ?>


            <?= /** @noEscape */ $_excl ?>
            <?php if ($taxHelper->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                (<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Incl. Tax')) ?> <?= /** @noEscape */ $_incl ?>)
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No shipping information available')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output look like: https://prnt.sc/HzZNfS1HRPHu